# How to use setValue in Monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

What is the proper way of setting a Monaco editors text content, without worrying about the undo stack? `monacoEditor.setValue("text")` seems to crash somewhere deep inside:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:1741 TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).create is not a function
    at D (textModel.ts:90)
    at f.setValue (textModel.ts:385)
    at t.setValue (commonCodeEditor.ts:211)
    at VueComponent.loadFile (ResourceViewer.vue?d447:85)
```

Comment: How are you configuring the editor? when you created the instance, did you use language and value, or passed a model?

Comment: The issue turned out that I was not passing in a string, but a JSON object. Testing with "text" did not work either because amdRequire turned out to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out that I was not passing in a string, but a JSON object. Testing with "text" did not work either because amdRequire turned out to be asynchronous.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Like what did you finally pass into the setValue() function? Did you convert the string into JSON and passed it?

Answer (score 29):

For the future traveler from google, the following code works for 0.2.0, after you have initialized the editor:

```
editor.getModel().setValue('some value');
```

Comment: That's erase the history of the editor , are there an other method to keep the history

Comment: Somehow that didn't work, and had to do it like this: `monaco.editor.getModels()[0].setValue('some text')`.